# Dealing with Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I wanted to ask a question about the way I am using Promises, since I'm not sure if I have over complicated things.

Firstly I am trying to create some methods that I want to execute one after another as the rely on the outcome of each previous method.

My project structure is like so

```
my_project
csv
helpers
  FileDownload.js
scripts
  getCSVData.js
app.js
```

Each file at the moment looks like

```
## FileDownload.js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(url, target) {
  return fetch(url)
  .then(function(res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var dest = fs.createWriteStream(target);
      res.body.pipe(dest)
      .on('finish', () => resolve()) // ** Resolve on success
      .on('error', reject);        // ** Reject on error
    });
  }).then(result => {
    console.log(`File saved at ${target}`)
    return result;
  });

}

## getCSVData.js

const file_download = require('../helpers/FileDownload')

function getPremierLeagueData() {
  file_download("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/E0.csv", "./csv/premier_league/premier_league.csv")
}

module.exports = {
  getPremierLeagueData: getPremierLeagueData
}

## app.js
const premier_league = require('./scripts/getCSVData')

premier_league.getPremierLeagueData()
  .then(function(result){ console.log(result)})
```

When running `node app.js` i get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

If I go back to my `FileDownload` function and `console.log(result)` that is undefined.

My confusion here is that because `resolve()` is called I am thinking that the Promise is resolved? So that should carry through to the `.then`.

I am clearly misunderstanding something here.

Comment: What do you expect `result` to be? Your promise fulfills with `undefined` after having written the file to the destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getPremierLeagueData` function does not return a Promise. It does not return anything…

You just need to return the result of `file_download`, which is already a Promise:

```js
function getPremierLeagueData() {
  return file_download(args)
}
```

Comment: Ah so I need to wrap that in a promise then? Is this where using a library like bluebird comes in so I can promisfyAll ?

Comment: @Richlewis No, you don't need to wrap anything. You just need to `return` it.

Comment: Your `FileDownload` module already returns a Promise when executed. Simply return the result of its execution in `getPremierLeagueData`, as shown in @VivekDoshi's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help there, I think i got confused a bit

Answer (score 1):

Need to return from `getPremierLeagueData`

```
function getPremierLeagueData() {
  return file_download("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/E0.csv", "./csv/premier_league/premier_league.csv")
}
```

OR ( Use new ES6 syntax )

```
const getPremierLeagueData = () => file_download("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/E0.csv", "./csv/premier_league/premier_league.csv")
```

---

> Note :

you can also reduce this

```
module.exports = {
  getPremierLeagueData: getPremierLeagueData
}
```

with

```
module.exports = { getPremierLeagueData }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done some minor changes in your files . You are neither resolving anything in FileDownload nor are you returning anything in getCSVData . Hence the final console will print nothing .Please try the code below

```
## FileDownload.js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function(url, target) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
     fetch(url)
    .then(function(res) {
       var dest = fs.createWriteStream(target);
       res.body.pipe(dest)
       .on('finish', function(data){
        console.log(`File saved at ${target}`)
        resolve(data)
       })
      .on('error', function(){
           reject();          
      })        // ** Reject on error

    })

 })
 } 



## getCSVData.js

const file_download = require('../helpers/FileDownload')

function getPremierLeagueData() {
  return  file_download("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/E0.csv", "./csv/premier_league/premier_league.csv")
}

module.exports = {
  getPremierLeagueData: getPremierLeagueData
}

## app.js
const premier_league = require('./scripts/getCSVData')

premier_league.getPremierLeagueData()
  .then(function(result){ console.log(result)})
```